# Does your code cater for double clicking?

Tags: user-interface, web, user-experience, double-click

More specifically, when developing websites/web applications, do you cater for users double clicking on elements that aren't originally designed to be double clicked?

I know this sounds like a slightly off-topic question but it's something I've only considered recently and something I'm genuinely curious about. There are certain users that we all know that will double click on elements in the browser, in fact they pretty much double click anything on the computer to action something. Granted, these people are usually the less experienced - but they are users nonetheless.

I had an issue a couple of weeks ago whereby I was making an ajax request onclientclick of a button. Double clicking the button caused unwanted behaviour, so I've put the necessary checks in place. Which led me to thinking that maybe I should be considering this for all elements on a web page.

Is this something you currently code around?

Answer (score 1):

We have a simple web form for making purchases, it just used ordinary form submission, no AJAX. And we found that some customers were accidentally purchasing twice, because they doubleclicked, or maybe the server was slow and they clicked a second time while waiting. So I put in some simple Javascript to disable the submit button after the click.